# Filter Source Code Management in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I am creating a maven job in Jenkins to check out and build  code from repository. I am actually trying to check out and build different project code from same repository using a single maven job. 
Is it possible to filter  the code checkout from repository using a parameterized  maven job(parameter to indicate which code has to be checked out)  . Do we have any label to identify which code has to be checked out?

Comment: Can you describe more details of your repo? Is it spread across multiple branches or in single branch and spread across folders? Git or SVN?

Comment: Svn across different folder

Answer (score 0):

Seems like answer is no. Native "Source Code Management" of Jenkins Maven job does not allow dynamic and filtered checkout.
What you can do instead is, use svn command line,

```
svn co http://subversion/project/trunk/${project} ${project}_checkout
```

and loop it over all the required list of projects passed as build parameters.